# Discrepancy between time & frequency domain RMS magnitude

Tags: fft, python, rms

I'm looking at complex baseband RF at a sample rate of 2.56 MHz. I've plotted the FFT of the entire spectrum, a 16 kHz segment of that spectrum, and the output of 160 decimation low pass filter that looks identical to the segment of the entire spectrum. So all of that looks as it should.

My problem is understanding amplitude/magnitude/power. I might be confusing the two. The signal in the 16 kHz segment has a maximum amplitude of about -58 dB. However, the RMS amplitude of the time domain samples is around .011 (or ~ -39dB). If I take the RMS value of the FFT output, the difference between the time domain magnitude and frequency domain magnitude is a factor of the square root of the number of samples (N). I'm scaling the FFT output by 1/N.

So I need to understand which to use. -58dB falls below the dynamic range of the ADC, and I'm receiving both real and spurious signals that sound like intermodulation there. The discrepancy concerns me because the filters have been designed with stopband attenuation minimum of 60dB (there are 6 filter stages, 5 half-band followed by an FIR with decimation factor of 5), and these signals are down in that range.

I looked at changing the scaling from 1 / N to 1 / sqrt(N) but the peaks are well over 100 even though the range of the time domain signal is (-1, 1), which doesn't make any sense to me.

My question, then, is how to reconcile the two different versions of the magnitude, and if both are valid, which to use when. Although I'm retired, I consider myself new at this. I'm a better programmer than mathematician, and these secrets are revealing themselves very slowly to me.

Here's the relevant bits of Python code I've been using for testing.

```
def plotfft(signal, sr, offset=0, scale=1, ylimits=[-80, 0], title="Spectrum"):
    # Set up x axis
    x_axis = (np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(signal.size, 1/sr)) + offset) / scale
    plt.xticks(ticks = x_axis[np.mod(x_axis, 50000 / scale) < (1 / scale)], minor=True)

    # Take fft, with magnitudes to y axis
    y_axis = np.abs(np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(signal))) / signal.size
    y_axis_db = 20 * np.log10(y_axis)

    plt.ylim(ylimits)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis_db)
    plt.show()

    # Return the RMS 
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(np.abs(y_axis * y_axis)))

if __name__ == "__main__"
    frms = plotfft(wavec, sr, offset=lo, scale=1E3, title=f"RTL-SDR {sr/1000} kHz LP6")

    rms = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.abs(wavec) * np.abs(wavec)))
    peak = np.max(np.abs(wavec))
    complex_mean = np.mean(np.real(wavec)) + 1j * np.mean(np.imag(wavec))
    wavec -= complex_mean
    std = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.abs(wavec) * np.abs(wavec)))
    print(f"RMS = {rms}, with DC offset removed = {std}")
    print(f"Frequency domain RMS = {frms}")
```

The above starts after the last stage of filtering, and replicates (successfully) the logic of the C code that is used for continuous monitoring.

[image: Program output]

```
RMS = 0.011212775775548913, with DC offset removed = 0.011153039706293706
Frequency domain RMS = 8.451947751336821e-05
```

Comment: If you want RMS in the time and frequency domain to match you need to scale  both forward and backward DFT by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$. That is the only scaling that conserves Perceval's theorem. Also note that the levels in the frequency domain are "densities". They depend on the bin width and hence the FFT length.

Comment: Thanks @Hilmar. Yes, scaling by 1 / sqrt(N) worked fine to match RMS. What happens though is that I see peaks of 115 (>20dB), which I can't get my head around, when the time domain amplitude is well under 0dB. It's not a thing I'd normally see on a spectrogram.

Comment: That's perfectly normal if your signal has some sinusoidal components. An extreme case a single sine wave (assuming RMS = 1). All the energy falls into 2 frequency bins and hence you will get two peaks with a value of $\sqrt{N/2}$ each. In other words: all the energy that's smeared out in the time is "bunched up" in the frequency domain, hence the frequency domain values must be high since the sums are the same.